# Why am I getting this error when the module facebook is mported?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import facebook
import facepy
from facepy import GraphAPI


graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
```

> > > friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       AttributeError: 'GraphAPI' object has no attribute 'get_connections'

Comment: pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk http://goo.gl/mUuIH

Comment: Third-Party http://goo.gl/rNFyW4

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook package on PyPI is messed up. It's not facebook that you want, but facebook-sdk.

Make sure you have the right one:

```
pip uninstall facebook  # Remove the broken package
pip install facebook-sdk  # Install the correct one
```

Comment: Can you share your version of facebook.py?

Answer (score 0):

You must to have [oauth_access_token:link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me?fields=id,name&version=v2.0) registered on FaceBook.

**Basic usage:**

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="I am writing on my wall!")
```

**Bibliography:**

> 1. pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk http://goo.gl/mUuIH
> 2. FB SDK Third-Party http://goo.gl/rNFyW4

Comment: I have several scripts working, and I am unable to get this one working.

Comment: there are some examples on FB SDK from github. See link nr. 1.

Comment: I created this on my macbook installing the SDK and it works, there must an issues on my raspberry PI